# 'MSDASQL' does not support the required transaction interface

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

He creado un linked server entre un Microsoft SQL Server 2000 y MariaDB Server 10.1.17.

Para ello he usado el conector ODBC versión 5.1 descargado de la web de MySQL.

El problema que me surge es al realizar transacciones distribuidas, por ejemplo:

```
    select * from mysql51...Candidato;

      update Candidato set nombre_candidato='Oscar' where id_candidato=6;
      update mysql51...Candidato set nombre_candidato='Oscar' where id_candidato=6;

    set XACT_ABORT ON

    BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION; 
      update Candidato set nombre_candidato='Juan' where id_candidato=6;
      update mysql51...Candidato set nombre_candidato='Juan' where id_candidato=6;
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
    GO

    select * from Candidato;
```

Al ejecutar esta bloque de código, los 2 primeros updates los realiza correctamente, mientras que los updates que se encuentran en el bloque BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION muestran el siguiente error:

```
OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'MSDASQL' IUnknown::QueryInterface returned 0x80004002].
Msg 7390, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The requested operation could not be performed because the OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' does not support the required transaction interface.
```

En las propiedades del provedor MSDASQL tengo configurado los siguientes parámetros:

[image: propiedades del provedor MSDASQL]

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido "avanzar" en cierto modo.

Revisando los pasos descritos en el hilo que pongo abajo, he visto que en las propiedades del DSN de ODBC no tenía marcada una casilla.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945435/sql-server-2000-linked-server/6651704#6651704

Ahora mismo el error que me muestra es el siguiente, si consigo solucionarlo modificaré la respuesta:

```
[OLE/DB provider returned message: [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Optional feature not supported]
OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'MSDASQL' ITransactionJoin::JoinTransaction returned 0x8004d00a].
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The operation could not be performed because the OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```